# How to change the position of the label in bar chart in Google Data Studio?

Tags: bar-chart, looker-studio

I want to change to position of the my bar chart value (which is a percentage), but I don't know how to do it. The percentage of the bar chart is in the right side, but it should be in the center. And the other percentage is also in the right side, but it should be out of the bar chart, in the right side too.

Bar chart 1 - Position of value
[image]

Bar chart 2 - Position of value
[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart.